# How do I safely add a new parameter to a stored procedure being used by many programs?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I have a stored procedure that is being used by many programs. Where do I add a `@NewParm` such that it doesn't break other programs using this SP? In the example below I put it after `@Parm4`, is this ok or should I place it after the `OUTPUT` parm?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spMyStoredProc] 
    @Parm1 varchar(20), 
    @Parm2 varchar(5),
    @Parm3 varchar(10),
    @Parm4 varchar(2),
    @NewParm nvarchar(5) = null, 
    @OutputParm varchar(100) OUTPUT
    ...
```

Comment: I'd leave the function interface as is and provide a new one with the additional parameter; the old one would then call the new one with an appropriate default for the new parameter.

Comment: One of *hope* that your calls to the procedure isn't relying on positional parameters but they could be, so as the end would be "safer". Though there's more than just making sure that the parameters are optional, you also need to ensure that the code within the procedure doesn't change, or that you end up introducing a performance issue with your new parameter. The part you ask about is one of several steps.

Comment: You should put it at the end in case someone is doing positional parameters.

Comment: @ThomA yea I'm just now realizing why doing named parameters is better...

Comment: @Charlieface everyone does positional. Yikes

Comment: Yup that's why I always use named parameters myself. Never know when someone decides to rearrange them. Either way, do you have any actual question now?

Comment: @Charlieface I just made a new SP and left the original one alone, per the first comment